# Naming a sheet with space in a VLookup function (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get certain information from a sheet and copying it to a different worksheet and my worksheets have long names (cannot change them for a reason)

I keep coming up with message "Compile Error: Expected List Separator or )" and 
I am pretty sure its to do with the sheet name unless I'm wrong?

Code:

```
Sub SALEXAMPLE()  
Dim names As String  
names = "Justin Jones"  
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(names, **salary sheets**.Range("A1:C10"), 2, False)  
MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Sal
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show your full name of `**salary sheets**` worksheet ? so we can simulate this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `Sheets` to reference the sheet you want :
 `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("salary sheets").Range(...`

```
Sub SALEXAMPLE()  
Dim names As String  
names = "Justin Jones"  
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(names, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("salary sheets").Range("A1:C10"), 2, False)  
MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Sal
End Sub
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. Thanks